# Flutter semantic label does not work with VoiceOver on iOS

Tags: flutter, accessibility

This is an app specifically for blind and partially sighted users and rely heavily on VoiceOver who mainly use the iPhone. Upgraded to Flutter 3.0.2 did a flutter clean, pub upgrade and pub get but the issue still persists. Running on an iPhone SE 2nd Gen with iOS 15.5

Any possible workaround would be much appreciated. Thanks.

### Steps to Reproduce

1. Execute `flutter run` on the code sample
2. Enable VoiceOver on iOS
3. Tap on any or all of the 3 displayed icons "compose", "camera" & "chat"

**Expected results:**

Expected the VoiceOver to read out the semantic labels: edit profile, camera screen & chat screen

**Actual results:**

VoiceOver instead reads out: compose, camera button, chat button
Even tried it with the "Semantics" widget with a label and excluding the children but the same issue (This works perfectly on Android 11 (OnePlus Nord2 CE) though)

**Code sample:**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'VoiceOver Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'VoiceOver Demo'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  int _currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {},
          child: IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.edit, semanticLabel: "edit profile",),
                tooltip: 'edit profile tooltip', onPressed: () {  },
          ),
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
        elevation: 5,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.camera_alt_outlined,
                        size: 36,
                        color: _currentIndex == 0 ? Colors.white:Colors.grey,
                        semanticLabel: "camera screen",
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        _currentIndex = 0;
                        print("Page 1");
                      }
            ),
            const Spacer(),
            IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.chat_outlined,
                          size: 36,
                          color: _currentIndex == 1 ? Colors.white:Colors.grey,
                          semanticLabel: "chat screen",
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          _currentIndex = 1;
                          print("Page 2");
                        }
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),// This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

**Few others I tried:**

```dart
      body: Center(
        child: Semantics(
          label: "edit profile",
          excludeSemantics: true,
          child: IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.edit,
                size: 36,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
              }
          ),
      )),
```

```dart
      body: Center(
        child: Semantics(
          onDidGainAccessibilityFocus: () {
            SemanticsService.announce("edit profile", TextDirection.ltr);
          },
          label: "edit profile label",
          excludeSemantics: true,
          child: IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.edit,
                size: 36,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
              }
          ),
      )),
```

**Logs:**

```
/Users/me/Projects/voiceoverdemo/voiceoverdemo_test_flutter/ios/Runner/Info.plist
[        ] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
           <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
           <plist version="1.0">
           <dict>
            <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
            <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
            <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
            <string>VoiceOver Test Flutter</string>
            <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
            <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
            <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
            <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
            <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
            <string>6.0</string>
            <key>CFBundleName</key>
            <string>voiceoverdemo_test_flutter</string>
            <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
            <string>APPL</string>
            <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
            <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
            <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
            <string>????</string>
            <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
            <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
            <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
            <true/>
            <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
            <string>LaunchScreen</string>
            <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
            <string>Main</string>
            <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
            <array>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
            </array>
            <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
            <array>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
            </array>
            <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
            <false/>
           </dict>
           </plist>

             {
               "simulator" : false,
               "operatingSystemVersion" : "15.5 (19F77)",
               "interface" : "usb",
               "available" : true,
               "platform" : "com.apple.platform.iphoneos",
               "modelCode" : "iPhone12,8",
               "identifier" : "XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
               "architecture" : "arm64e",
               "modelUTI" : "com.apple.iphone-se-1",
               "modelName" : "iPhone SE",
               "name" : "Me's iPhone"
             },
```

```
flutter analyze:

Analyzing voiceoverdemo_test_flutter...                                         
No issues found! (ran in 2.5s)
```

```
flutter doctor -v

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.5, on macOS 12.3.1 21E258 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 2.10.5 at /Users/me/software/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 5464c5bac7 (8 weeks ago), 2022-04-18 09:55:37 -0700
    • Engine revision 57d3bac3dd
    • Dart version 2.16.2
    • DevTools version 2.9.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/me/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.4.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2021.3.3)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
    • Flutter plugin version 66.0.3
    • Dart plugin version 213.7371

[✓] VS Code (version 1.68.0)
    • VS Code at /Users/me/Software/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.42.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • Me's iPhone (mobile) • XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXX • ios            • iOS 15.5 19F77
    • Chrome (web)               • chrome                    • web-javascript • Google Chrome 102.0.5005.115

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/5812030/174106131-a6be4e0c-e650-46cf-87ea-0c635c0d04c5.jpg

This works fine in the simulator with the Accessibility Inspector:

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/5812030/174129522-29ff6a1f-38a4-4593-93c5-4f34e08e891e.png

Recording:

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/5812030/174270320-159d3fb7-135a-417b-b9d1-c3a8e2f526f1.MP4

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue. For some reason a setting was enabled on my iPhone. When I switched it off it worked perfectly.

Settings -> Accessibility -> Voice Over -> VoiceOver Recognition -> Screen Recognition -> Apply to Apps

This setting had the app added to it. When I removed the app from this list it worked fine